# POST JSON with mule esb

Tags: post, mule, esb

I need to get a json content and i need to transmit this json to a web service who will send a push and resend to my application a response which is in json format. and in my application i have to traite this response if the push is sent its ok if not, an email must be sent. for the client application i'm using Postman (Google Chrome extension). but for transmission i tried a lot of things. but i'm a little confused i don't know what component to use i tried this code is it correct and suffisant or there is something to change to make my code better?!
 need i to connect the two flows? because i have a variable email in the fist flow which i call in the second. If yes how can i do this. thank you in advance.
NB: I'm using mule 2.5.0 CE.

```
<db:mysql-config name="MySQL_Configuration" host="localhost" port="3306" user="root" database="mulesoft" doc:name="MySQL Configuration"/>
    <smtp:gmail-connector name="Gmail" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Gmail"/>


<flow name="flows1Flow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="8083"  encoding="UTF-8" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
        <set-variable variableName="msg" value="#[message.payload.msg]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <set-variable variableName="token" value="#[message.payload.token]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select * from push where token = #[message.payload['token']]]]></db:parameterized-query>
        </db:select>
        <foreach doc:name="For Each">
            <set-variable variableName="email" value="#[message.payload.email]" doc:name="Variable"/>
        </foreach>
        <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="WS.com" port="8080" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" path="api.php/push/send_test_push"/>
    <logger message="#[message.payload.token]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>


<flow name="flows1Flow2">
        <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="HTTP-Puller-Scheduler" repeatInterval="1000" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="Quartz" repeatCount="0">
            <quartz:event-generator-job/>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="WS.com" port="8080" method="GET" doc:name="HTTP" path="api.php/push/send_test_push"/>
   <json:json-to-object-transformer
            returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[message.payload.success=1]">
                <logger message="its ok" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                    <set-payload
                        value="Dear Mail Crawler,
                    \n\n No spam to my email, please!"
                        doc:name="Set Payload" />
                    <smtp:outbound-endpoint host="smtp.gmail.com"
                        port="587" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SMTP" connector-ref="Gmail"
                        from="Rajeun" password="pass" subject="Mule Test with Velocity Transformer"
                        to="#[flowVars['email']]" user="mymail%40gmail.com" />

            </otherwise>
</choice>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have use flow variable email in the first flow

```
<set-variable variableName="email" value="#[message.payload.email]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

You will not be getting the value `#[flowVars['email']]` in second flow since you have used a flow variable whose scope is limited to a flow.

For that you need Session variable in the first flow instead of a flow variable like the following :-

```
<set-session-variable variableName="email" value="#[message.payload.email]" doc:name="Session Variable"/>
```

and extract the value in flow2 as follows :-

```
#[sessionVars['email']]
```

**UPDATE**

Use the url in following way in outbound,
for example if your external url is  `http://localhost:8082/getData/retrieve` then use the following in outbound:-

```
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="GET" address="http://localhost:8082/getData/retrieve" contentType="application/json" doc:name="HTTP"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your help. After changing my code and running i get this error: http://pastebin.com/9dGrrJe9 another question, I recover the response of the WS using http (GET). there is a way to run the get method that after the arrival of the response. Or if the quartz is the only solution how can i stop the listening after the arriving of the response. thank you again.

Comment: The way you are using url is wrong,.. paste the full url in the address attribute of  http:outbound-endpoint and remove port and host from there

Comment: <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="slice.WS.com/api.php/push/send_test_push"  method="GET" doc:name="HTTP" />
 this is what i changed but when i run my applcation the deploy is failed

Comment: paste the full url here